# Qt creator debugging : "Temporarily disabling breakpoints for unloaded shared library"

Tags: debugging, dll, qt-creator

I am working on a Windows command line app that uses a few DLLs. I am developing using Qt creator and therefore using its debugger, which was working until now. But recently, it stopped hitting breakpoints in one of the DLLs by telling me every time that DLL was needed :

```
Temporarily disabling breakpoints for unloaded shared library "<path-to-my-DLL>"
```

This is all the weirder because it outputs this exactly as many times as I know that the DLL will be used in the main app :

```
Temporarily disabling breakpoints for unloaded shared library "<path-to-my-DLL>"
Temporarily disabling breakpoints for unloaded shared library "<path-to-my-DLL>"
Temporarily disabling breakpoints for unloaded shared library "<path-to-my-DLL>"
...
```

Also, I know the DLL really is called exactly as many times as expected by the main app - and generally works properly - because I can see some meaningful output produced by it. But the breakpoint I have set in (one of) the source file(s) of the DLL never gets hit ... anymore (though it used to, last I debugged it).

Also, I can still debug in other DLLs & parts of the app.

A little more info : I in fact run a Python script from the console which will run the main app which uses the DLL once. When I have done this, I switch over to Qt Creator and use "Debug > Start Debugging > Attach to Running Application" (or sometimes "Attach to Unstarted Application", either way works as far as attaching and starting the debugger is concerned).

Any hints as to where to look for explanations of this change in behavior ?